# enable PRU beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I want to operate pins of beaglebone black for programmable run-time unit.
My "beaglebone black rev c" details are as follows

```
cat /etc/dogtag 
BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2016-05-13

cat /etc/debian_version 
8.4
cat /proc/cmdline 

console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=UUID=3259b2e9-2c2b-4d8a-ac11-ed5a7a76f1d4 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M quiet cape_universal=enable

cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
0: PF----  -1 
 1: PF----  -1 
 2: PF----  -1 
 3: PF----  -1 
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-UART4
```

I have tried

```
config-pin -q p9.22
```

it returns

```
P9_22 pinmux file not found!
cape-universala overlay not found
run "config-pin overlay cape-universala" to load the cape
```

I want to operate pins using commandline as well as c program

Can anybody guide me how to do it?
Can you suggest references for this?
Any kind of help will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For the PRU you should load the corresponding overlay.
Please take a look at [overlays collection](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/bb.org-overlays/tree/master/src/arm) by Robert Nelson:
You will need at least one of *PRU* dtbo files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable universal overlay in uEnv.txt file.

1. `sudo nano /boot/uEnv.txt`
2. `cape-universala overlay=1`

save and reboot your Beaglebone black.

After reboot.

```
config-pin -l P9_29
```